# Array de posição de memória

Tags: assembly, x86, 8086

Estou fazendo uma implementação de um jogo em [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) no [Proteus](https://www.labcenter.com/).

Eu sorteio dois números aleatórios de 1 até 99 e preciso gerar no LCD uma imagem referente aos números que eu gerei.

Exemplo: Se eu gerar o **número 1** a imagem que vai aparecer no display é

[image: Numero 1]

Se eu gerar o **número 2** a imagem que vai aparecer no display é

[image: Numero 2]

Implementação foi feita da seguinte maneira:

```
.DATA    
SEED DW 0 ;Armazena o número aleatório de 1 ~ 99
NUMBER1 DW 0 ;Guarda o primeiro número gerado  
NUMBER2 DW 0 ;Guarda o segundo número gerado

IMG_NUMBER1 DW ? ;variavel aux para armazenar a IMG do primeiro numero gerado
IMG_NUMBER2 DW ? ;variavel aux para armazenar a IMG do segundo numero gerado

IMG_NUMERO_1 db 8, 6
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 030H,0D0H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,060H,080H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,080H,060H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,0D0H,030H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,00CH,034H
db 0C2H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,001H,002H,002H,002H,002H
db 002H,002H,002H,002H,001H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,0C2H
db 034H,00CH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 0F0H,00FH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,004H,0FEH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,00FH,0F0H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 003H,01CH,060H,080H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,002H,003H,002H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,080H,060H,01CH,003H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,001H,002H,002H,002H,004H,004H,004H,008H,008H,010H,020H
db 020H,010H,008H,008H,004H,004H,004H,002H,002H,002H,001H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H
db 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H

IMG_NUMERO_2 db 8,6
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 030H,0D0H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,060H,080H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,080H,060H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,010H,0D0H,030H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,00CH,034H
DB 0C2H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,001H,002H,002H,002H,002H
DB 002H,002H,002H,002H,001H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,0C2H
DB 034H,00CH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 0F0H,00FH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,004H,082H,042H,022H,01CH,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,00FH,0F0H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 003H,01CH,060H,080H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,003H,002H,002H,002H,003H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,080H,060H,01CH,003H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,001H,001H,002H,002H,002H,004H,004H,004H,008H,008H,010H,020H
DB 020H,010H,008H,008H,004H,004H,004H,002H,002H,002H,001H,001H,000H,000H,000H,000H
DB 000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H,000H

..... IMG_NUMERO_3, IMG_NUMERO_4 ... até 99
```

No código escrevi assim para gerar o número aleatório e guardar nas variáveis auxiliares para comparação no final do jogo:

```
CALL RANDOM
MOV NUMBER1, SEED ;Guarda o primeiro numero gerado
CALL RANDOM
MOV NUMBER2, SEED ;Guarda o segundo numero gerado
```

Eu tenho NUMBER1 e NUMBER2 os valores dos números aleatórios gerados.

Eu fiz da seguinte maneira para buscar o número gerado e armazenar a posição de memória da imagem referente ao número: ( Armazeno em BL antes de chamar `COMPARE_NMB`, o valor 0 para buscar a imagem do NUMBER1 e 1 para a NUMBER2; Em AX contém o valor do NUMBER*)

```
COMPARE_NMB:
   PUSHF
   PUSH BX
   PUSH AX
   PUSH CX

   CMP AX, 1
   JE JE_1 ;PULA PRO METODO SE FOR 1   
   CMP AX, 2
   JE JE_2 ;PULA PRO METODO SE FOR 2
   CMP AX, 3
   JE JE_3
   ... assim por diante até 99 ...
```

Para cada **J**ust **E**quals eu chamo assim:

```
JE_1:
    LEA SI, IMG_NUMERO_1
JMP CONTINUE
JE_2:
    LEA SI, IMG_NUMERO_2
JMP CONTINUE
....

CONTINUE:
   CMP BL, 0 ;VERIFICAR AONDE ARMAZENAR
   JE ARMAZENAR_IMG1
   JNE ARMAZENAR_IMG2 
...
ARMAZENAR_IMG1:
    MOV IMG_NUMBER1, SI
JMP FINALIZAR
ARMAZENAR_IMG2:
    MOV IMG_NUMBER2, SI
JMP FINALIZAR
```

Mas não acho que é a melhor solução.

Alguém saberia um método mais prático?

Criar uma nova variável e armazenar como fosse um **array de posições de memória**, se eu querer a **imagem1** eu somente iria fazer `posicoesImagens[NUMBER1]`, ou **imagem2**, `posicoesImagens[NUMBER2]`, algo assim.

---

Obs: Sim, atualmente eu gerei 99 variáveis para armazenar cada imagem referente a cada número. Meu editor está até travando pela quantidade de informações no código.

*Escrevi 500 linhas só para comparar qual é o número gerado.
E tive que escrever 2178 linhas referente as imagens de cada número.*

**DS** significa Data Segment.

Comment: Não programo em Assembly, logo não sei se você fez aí, mas ... Não tem como fazer um `loop` pra armazenar os valores em cada variável, acrescentando +1 no nome da variável??
 Pesquisando aqui, encontrei [este link que fala sobre loop no assbemly](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_loops.htm), talvez possa ser útil. É possível compilar online seu código para teste [AQUI!](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/try_asm.php)

Comment: @MarcosHenzel não sei como fazer o que você está falando, meu conhecimento está conforme eu coloquei no código acima. Quero remover as 500 linhas de comparações que eu fiz e opcionalmente se alguém souber algum método para que em vez de criar 99 variáveis dos números, eu precise criar apenas 1 imagem e colocar o número no centralizado dentro dessa imagem em tempo de execução.

Comment: Não trabalho com Assembly, mas no seu caso não seria mais apropriado o uso de alguma matriz (array)? Nesta página deve haver alguma informação útil: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arrays.htm

Comment: @M8n sim, conforme coloquei ali. 8,6

Comment: Para extender as sugestões, uma array seria essencialmente uma lista de ponteiros, que são "localizações" ou endereços de uma imagem específica. No seu caso poderia ser uma array de imagens (ordem de menor para maior), ou, quis dizer, uma array de ponteiros de uma imagem específica. Cada ponteiro deve ter o mesmo tamanho em bytes. Para pegar a localização (ou endereço) do ponteiro basta fazer `endereçoDaLista + númeroDaImagem * tamanhoDoPonteiro`, por exemplo. Infelizmente não sei muito assembly, por isso não posso ajudar tanto :/

Comment: A posição da primeira imagem está começando do 1, mas poderia começar no 0. Isso vai depender de como a array é armazenada na memória tbm.

Comment: (Meu comentário ficou meio confuso, mas blz :v)

Comment: @PolarDigit bem, mas é isso que eu quero fazer, mas não tenho conhecimento de como fazer. Criar uma nova variável e armazenar como fosse um array de posições de memória, se eu querer a **imagem1** eu somente iria fazer `posicoesImagens[1]`, ou **imagem2**, `posicoesimagem[2]`, algo assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que todas as imagens tenham o mesmo tamanho, logo, basta você armazenar num vetorzão. Aí na hora de acessar você só precisa do endereço inicial e do salto a fazer, então ficaria simplesmente:

```
endereco_inicial + (salto * tamanho_de_cada_imagem)
```

Outra coisa a pensar é que a única coisa que muda entre as imagens é o número central, então ocuparia menos espaço você definir o badge e imprimir o número dentro do badge.

Inclusive os próprios números basta ter de 0 a 9 a única coisa que muda é a posição onde você irá imprimir, então dá para economizar bastante espaço, mas claro que fazendo isso você teria um código um pouco maior para poder fazer as diferentes impressões.

Answer (score 1):

Cria a imagem com o nome por exemplo img_01.jpg, img_02.jpg...img_99.jpg
e usa um substring (não sei como é feito em assembly) para abrir a imagem que corresponde ao número
algo do Tipo:

```
"img_" + suavariavel + ".jpg"
"img_" & suavariavel & ".jpg"
```